# color change pdfpagediff.sty

Tags: color, pdfpagediff

`pdfpagediff.sty` is one of a nice tool for comparing two PDFs with less changes. Is it possible to change the second layer color, currently it produced with `30% black`, need to change this to `Red` or any color...

MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpagediff}

\begin{document}

\color{red}

\FirstDoc{file_3P}%you can change any pdf file name
\SecondDoc{file_5P}%you should give the modified pdf file name

\layerPages{file_3P}{file_5P}


\end{document}
```

color was mentioned in the package document as like:

[image]

Please advise

Comment: Please provide a *complete* Minimum Working Example.

Comment: Are you sure the colour difference is produced automatically by `pdfpagediff`? The manual and the actual test documents show that one of the PDFs being compared has been *generated* with a different default colour. To do this, just put `\color{red}` in your document preamble before you compile and the default colour will be set to red.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried, but no result....

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Now the MWE was posted, I thought that MWE was not required for this, anyway, sorry....

Comment: @MadyYuvi, as I read the `pdfpagediff` documentation you don't put the red colour in your MWE, but `file_5P.tex`. It's not automatic.

Comment: Your MWE will not use 30% grey in either `file_5P.pdf` or `file_3P.pdf`. You must manually change the colour in `file_5P.pdf` when you compile it. Then do the comparison.